# Trouble using Sahi function _setValue() on an HTML5 textbox that utilizes validation data attributes

Tags: html, sahi

I've tried inserting text into a textbox on my HTML5 login page but it isn't working. The controller finds the element okay and when the script is played back it even logs the case as a success, but the text is not being populated.

Here is the source for the textbox:

`<input id="Username" class="standard defaultfocus input-validation-error" type="text" value="" name="Username" maxlength="100" data-val-required="Please enter a valid Email Address" data-val-regex-pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9_%+-]+)*\@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$" data-val-regex="Please enter a valid Email Address" data-val="true"></input>`

Here is the Sahi script:

`_setValue(_textbox("Username"), "email@email.com");`

Any idea how to get Sahi to fill in this texbox?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue required an edit to one of the .js files packaged with Sahi.  The change is described here:

http://sahi.co.in/forums/discussion/4790/solution-to-run-the-script-on-firefiox-20-#Item_1